# Does Solr have a folder watcher ?

Tags: solr

I am using `Solr` 7.2 to index 'document files' using Post.

However, i want this to rerun every time there is a change to the document folder.

So i am using Jenkins with Folder Watcher trigger (`FSTrigger`) which calls the POST to re-index like this :-

```
/opt/solr/bin/solr delete -c resumes

sudo -u solr /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c resumes -d /opt/solr/example/files/conf

/opt/solr/bin/post -c resumes /home/chak/Documents
```

Is there a folder watcher in `Solr` itself, so i can avoid using Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1):

No, Solr does not have any watch capabilities - seeing as it's also meant to be running as a cluster on multiple server, I'm pretty sure that's functionality that would be considered to be external to Solr (possibly integrated into the `post` tool if any).

That being said, you don't have to use something as complex as Jenkins to implement that. Using `inotifywait` you could [implement the same functionality with a couple of lines of bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files).